# a.getLabelConfig is not a function

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to show tooltip by default on load. But the code I've been able to find:

```
chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[0].points[0]]);
```

and the like only gives me this error:

```
a.getLabelConfig is not a function
```

I read somewhere that `chart.tooltip` may not be ready, but I'm running this from a self-invoked function after creating the chart, so I should be good to go.

Has anyone experienced anything similar, and found a solution?

Comment: I have the same `a.getLabelConfig is not a function` bug, can't find a solution for it.
It seems to be intermittent.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of use `tooltip.refresh`:

- when you have shared tooltip: `chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[0].points[0]])`
- when you have non-shared tooltip: `chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].points[0])`